# Find the minimum and the maximum of two variable function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, maxima-minima

The function defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$
\begin{align*}f(x,y)= \frac{xy(xy+4)}{x^2+y^2+1}\end{align*}
Find each of the maximum and minimum values of the function if they are exist, Show that if they are not exist.

First I tried to find the first partial derivatives and the second partial derivatives but, since the function $f(x,y)$ is a fraction, they are so complex functions. I could not find the critical points clearly as well. Is this the right way to proceed with this kind of fractioning question or is there another convenient way?
Can we reduce this function into a simple one? I tried but could not reach for a good one. any hints would be appreciated.
\begin{align*}f_x &= \frac{2xy^4+4y^3+2xy^2+4y-4x^2y}{(x^2+y^2+1)^2}\\
f_y&= \frac{2x^4y+4x^3+2x^2y+4x-4xy^2}{(x^2+y^2+1)}
\end{align*}

Comment: @Asher2211 Yes that is true for all $x, y\in \mathbb{R}^2$. How does this help to show the existence of min and max?

Comment: $f(x,y) = \frac{xy(xy+4)}{x^2+y^2+1} = \frac{(xy+2)^2-4}{x^2+y^2+1}$ if $(xy+2)^2 \geq 4$ then the function is coercive. Am I right?

Comment: Polar coordinates may be more enlightening.  It will be clear there is no global maximum and where the minima are.

Comment: @boojum How do we clearly say it does not have a global maximum? I know that if a function is coercive for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^2$ it has a global minimizer.

Comment: The numerator has a largest term which increases with distance from the origin to the fourth power, while the denominator only increases with distance squared.

Comment: @boojum fourth power?? sorry I cannot see it

Comment: You have $ \ x^2y^2 + 4 xy \ = \ r^4 \sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \theta + \ 4r^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta \ $ in polar coordinates; the denominator is only $ \ r^2 + 1 \ \ . $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the denominator $x^2 + y^2 + 1 \ge 1$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$.  So $f$ is well-defined and continuous.  Next, we note that $f \ge -4$ for all $x,y$, since $$xy(xy+4) = (xy+2)^2 - 4.$$  So we know that a minimum must exist.*  As for a maximum, we have for $|x| > 1$ $$f(x,x) > \frac{x^4}{2x^2 + 1} \ge \frac{x^4}{2(x^2+x^2)} = \frac{x^2}{4},$$ so $f$ has no global maximum.

To find the minimum, it is worth considering $$f(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta) = \frac{r^2 \sin 2\theta (r^2 \sin 2\theta + 8)}{4 (r^2 + 1)}. \tag{1}$$  Regarding $r$ as fixed, we note $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} = 4 r^2 \cos 2\theta (4 + r^2 \sin 2\theta),$$ so any minimum would satisfy $\partial f/\partial \theta = 0$, implying for $\theta \in (-\pi, \pi]$ $$\theta \in \left\{ \pm \frac{\pi}{4}, \pm \frac{3\pi}{4}, \frac{1}{2} \arcsin \left(-\tfrac{4}{r^2} \right) \right \}.$$  Of these, clearly if $0 \le r < 2$, the last root is invalid.  Otherwise, we can substitute back into Equation $(1)$ and show that there are no critical points for $r > 0$. The other possibilities are easily checked for critical points with respect to $r$, which I leave as an exercise.

---

*Note.  Technically, it doesn't have to have a minimum, since a function like $e^x$ does not have a minimum although it is bounded below by $0$.  But it does suggest searching for one.

Answer (score 1):

For the critical points: factor out $2y$ from $f_x$ and $2x$ from $f_y$.  Observe that neither $x=0$ or $y=0$ gives a solution.  Subtract both remaining equations, it factors in
$$(y^2-x^2)(xy+4)=0.$$
From here the critical pints are easily found.